# Installing Pyqt4 with brew

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pyqt, homebrew

Im working with brew to install PyQt on python3 but I cant seem to get it to work

I ran `brew install pyqt` and `brew doctor` to fix all possible errors but still when running my code I keep getting

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

If I run `echo $PATH` im getting `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Can someone please guide me on fixing this problem? I am also using PyCharm but I still get the same error if I run in terminal `python3` then `import pyqt`

please help me :( im really new in this but I tried everything that I could find in google

thanks!

PD: Running `brew test pyqt` does not bring an error but it does not open. Also I installed python3 with brew and im currently running it from `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use PyQt4 with Python 3, you should use this command to tell homebrew:

`brew install PyQt --with-python3`

Comment: Due to a naming change in brew this command is now:  `brew install PyQt --with-python`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Installing using the instructions of Longhanks did not work as it said it was already installed. 
I got it working with

`brew reinstall PyQt --with-python3`

Answer (score 0):

**The following method is for python 2.7. You can replace the `2.7` into your current python version like 3.4 (enter the directory to see which to use).**

Because by default the python package is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is not included in python library
try:

```
mkdir -p /Users/zgf/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/zgf/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

where `zgf` should be replaced by your username in OSX.

You can also copy the relevant files from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` into your personal python site package directory or public site package directory (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages) if you can root.